I wrote a classifier in C++ but it doesn't learn and returns the same loss each epoch
I wrote a classifier in C++ and tried training it on MNIST set but it doesn't learn. Because I am using log loss, it returns a loss of -ln(1/10) basically random chance. I tried tinkering with my hyperparams but so far nothing has worked. I implemented Xavier initialization for better weight initialization and it worked for a different regression task but it seems to not be working here.
Here's a part of my code where I implement the model:
#include <iostream>
#include "layers.cpp"
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class MLP 
{
    private:
        int input_dim, num_neurons, output_dim;
        string activations;
        FCLayer fc1;
        FCLayer fc2;
        FCLayer fc3;
        double learning_rate;

    public:

        MLP(int input_dim, int num_neurons, int output_dim, double learning_rate, string activations)
        {
            this->input_dim = input_dim;
            this->num_neurons = num_neurons;
            this->output_dim = output_dim;
            this->learning_rate = learning_rate;
            this->activations = activations;

            this->fc1 = FCLayer(input_dim, num_neurons, activations);
            this->fc2 = FCLayer(num_neurons, num_neurons, activations);
            this->fc3 = FCLayer(num_neurons, output_dim, activations);
        }

        vector<vector<double>> forward(vector<vector<double>> x)
        {
            // Forward pass
            vector<vector<double>> out = fc1.forward(x);
            out = fc2.forward(out);
            out = fc3.forward(out);
            out = Softmax(out); // To generate a probability distribution across all the classes. Need to also update backprop to incorporate derivative of softmax.
            return out;
        }

        double cross_entropy_loss(vector<vector<double>> preds, vector<vector<double>> true_vals) {

            double loss = 0.0;
            double loss_const = 1e-9;

            for(int i = 0; i<preds.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<preds[0].size(); j++) {
                    loss += -true_vals[i][j] * log(preds[i][j] + loss_const);
                }
            }

            return loss/preds.size();
        }

        double get_classification_loss(vector<vector<double>> x, vector<vector<double>> val){
            
        }

        void backpass(vector<vector<double>> true_vals){

            vector<vector<double>> preds = this->forward(this->fc1.input_data);

            vector<vector<double>> dlda(preds.size(), vector<double>(true_vals[0].size(), 0.0));

            for(int i = 0; i<preds.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<preds[0].size(); j++){
                    dlda[i][j] = -true_vals[i][j] / preds[i][j];
                }
            }

            vector<vector<double>> softmax_der = Softmax_derivative(preds);

            // dlda = loss_der * softmax_der (hadamard product in this case because every element individually results in same output through softmax regardless of order in the row)
            dlda = hadamard(dlda, softmax_der);

            // Initiating backpass
            vector<vector<double>>third_grad = this->fc3.backprop(dlda);
            this->fc3.update_params(this->learning_rate);

            vector<vector<double>>second_grad = this->fc2.backprop(third_grad); // Debugging step -- Removed the transpose operation third grad operation
            this->fc2.update_params(learning_rate);

            vector<vector<double>> first_grad = this->fc1.backprop(second_grad);
            this->fc1.update_params(learning_rate);
        }

        void train(int num_epochs, double learning_rate, vector<vector<double>> x, vector<vector<double>> y){
            this->learning_rate = learning_rate;

            for(int epoch = 0; epoch<num_epochs; epoch++){
                vector<vector<double>> preds = this->forward(x);
                this->backpass(y);
                double loss = this->cross_entropy_loss(preds, y);;

                if((epoch+1) % 10 == 0){
                    cout << "Epoch: " << (epoch+1) << " || Loss: " << loss << "\n";
                }
            }
        }

        double evaluate(vector<vector<double>> x, vector<vector<double>> y) {
            vector<vector<double>> results = this->forward(x);
            double accuracy = 0.0;
            vector<int> correct_args = argmax(y);
            vector<int> predicted_args = argmax(results);

            for(int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++){
            if(correct_args[i] == predicted_args[i]){
                accuracy = accuracy + 1;
            }
            }

            return accuracy/y.size();
        }
};

And here's the math file where I wrote most of the math functions needed including weights and biases initialization:
#include "math.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <iostream>


// Global random number generator and distribution
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(-1.0, 1.0);

std::vector<std::vector<double>> Multiply_matrices(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& A, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& B) {
    if (A[0].size() != B.size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("The number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix.");
    }

    // Dimensions of the resulting matrix
    size_t rows = A.size();
    size_t cols = B[0].size();
    size_t inner_dim = B.size();

    // Initialize the result matrix with zeros
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result(rows, std::vector<double>(cols, 0.0));

    // Perform matrix multiplication
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < inner_dim; ++k) {
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


std::vector<double> Multiply_vector_matrix(std::vector<double>& data, std::vector<std::vector<double>>& weights)
{
    if(data.size() != weights.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("The second matrix should have the same number of rows as that of columns in the first matrix.");
    }

    std::vector<double> output(weights[0].size(), 0.0);

    for(int i = 0; i<weights[0].size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<data.size(); j++)
            {
                output[i] += data[j] * weights[j][i];
            }
        }
    

    return output;
}

std::vector<double> multiply_vectors(std::vector<double> a, std::vector<double> b)
{
    if(a.size() != b.size())
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("The two vectors should have the same size.");
    }

    std::vector<double> output(a.size(), 0.0);

    for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        output[i] = a[i] * b[i];
    }

    return output;
}

std::vector<double> Add_vectors(std::vector<double> data, std::vector<double> biases)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<biases.size(); i++){
        data[i] += biases[i];
    }

    return data;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> Add_biases(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix, const std::vector<double>& biases) {
    if (matrix.empty() || biases.empty() || matrix[0].size() != biases.size()) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Matrix and biases dimensions do not match.");
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result = matrix;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < result[0].size(); ++j) {
            result[i][j] += biases[j];
        }
    }

    return result;
}



double getRandomDouble() {
    return dis(gen);
}

double getXavierValue(int input_dim, int output_dim) {
    std::normal_distribution<> d(0, std::sqrt(2.0 / (input_dim + output_dim)));
    return d(gen);
}

// Function to initialize the matrix with Xavier initialization
std::vector<std::vector<double>> initializeMatrix(int rows, int cols) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(rows, std::vector<double>(cols));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = getXavierValue(rows, cols);
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}

std::vector<double> initializeBias(int size) {
    std::vector<double> bias(size);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        bias[i] = getXavierValue(1, size);
    }

    return bias;
}

// Function to print the matrix
void printMatrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix) {
    for(const auto& row : matrix) {
        for(const auto& val : row) {
            std::cout << val << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n \n";
    }
}

void printvector(const std::vector<double>& vec) {
    for(const auto& val : vec) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}


std::vector<std::vector<double>> transposeMatrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix) {
    if (matrix.empty()) return {}; // Return an empty matrix if input is empty

    int rows = matrix.size();
    int cols = matrix[0].size();
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> transposedMatrix(cols, std::vector<double>(rows));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            transposedMatrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    return transposedMatrix;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> hadamard(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix1, const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& matrix2) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result(matrix1.size(), std::vector<double>(matrix2[0].size()));

    for(int i = 0; i<matrix1.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<matrix2[0].size(); j++){
            result[i][j] = matrix1[i][j] * matrix2[i][j];
        }  
    }

    return result;
}

std::vector<double> calculate_bias_derivatives(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& dldz) {
    // Number of neurons (columns) in dldz
    int num_neurons = dldz[0].size();
    // Initialize bias_der vector with zeros
    std::vector<double> bias_der(num_neurons, 0.0);
    
    // Sum the gradients for each neuron across all samples in the batch
    for (int i = 0; i < dldz.size(); ++i) { // Iterate over rows (samples)
        for (int j = 0; j < num_neurons; ++j) { // Iterate over columns (neurons)
            bias_der[j] += dldz[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return bias_der;
}

std::vector<int> argmax(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>& x){
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (const auto& row : x) {
        double maxVal = row[0];
        int maxIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < row.size(); ++i) {
            if (row[i] > maxVal) {
                maxVal = row[i];
                maxIdx = i;
            }
        }
        result.push_back(maxIdx);
    }

    return result;
}

You can go through the rest of the code here: https://github.com/GraphicsMonster/MNIST-Classification-C-Plus-Plus
Any sort of help will be much appreciated!
